# Outer measure defined in terms of open intervals vs. closed intervals

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

This should be a simple question (it's been a long summer break....). I am reviewing some measure theory and noticed in my notes from a class that we defined the exterior measure in terms of the infimum of coverings of closed cubes. But in Royden, it is defined in terms of the infimum of coverings of open cubes. It doesn't seem like too much of a stretch to say these are equivalent, but I wanted to check the details. Does it follow simply from the fact that the exterior measure of an open cube is equal to the exterior measure of the closure of that cube?

*Edit, I should say rectangles rather than cubes above.

** Edit 2, so in my notes we are actually defining the exterior measure in terms of closed cubes for arbitrary dimension. In Royden, it seems like it was only talking about 1-d, and it seems like our 1-d cube and rectangle are equivalent (that is, they are just an interval). So now I'm rather unsure. Can exterior measure (in arbitrary dimension) be defined equivalently in terms of rectangles or cubes? Furthermore, whether cubes or rectangles, can it be defined as open or closed?

Comment: You are working on $\mathbb{R}$ or some higher dimensions?

Comment: @vishal I was thinking $R^d$, so arbitrary. Additionally, in my class notes, we define it in terms of closed cubes, so closed intervals if we are considering 1-D. But what I was reading in Royden was just for $R$, but I presume they may be equivalent for any dimension?

Comment: They are equivalent. Look at "Measure theory and Integration" by G.De. Barra. He discusses this for $\mathbb{R}$ and "Analysis III" by Herbert Amann and Joachim Escher discuss it for higher dimensions too.

Comment: Those references are surely great but I think that the question at hand can be answered immediately. Just observe that any closed cube covering is contained in an open cube covering which is only an $\varepsilon$ bigger, and vice versa.

Comment: @Giuseppe, thanks, I thought so. What about rectangle vs. cube? Would it again follow since the exterior measure of a rectangle in terms of cubes would be the volume of the rectangle and vice versa?

Comment: What you say doesn't sound very convincing. I would say: any cube covering is a rectangle covering too, so the rectangle outer measure is smaller. Any rectangle covering induces a cube covering with the same measure (this should be proved, though), so the reverse inequality is true too.